# Access JavaScript Window object from an external page

Tags: javascript, php, puppeteer

Given a URL, is there a way to access the JavaScript Window object generated on the client side when running it?

Comment: it's not really clear. What are you trying to achieve? When and from where would you run this URL? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to have a web page with an input box. When entering a URL in that input and hitting "inspect" you should be able to check if that site is using jQuery or not.